# Difference in Effectiveness Between Different Whole House Surge Protectors?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, surge-suppression

I'm trying to determine the most effective type of whole home surge protection to install on a Eaton BR type circuit breaker panel. The options I've looked at are all made by Eaton: CHSPT2ULTRA, BRNSURGE, and the BR230SUR.  The CHSPT2ULTRA is the most difficult install for me since its an external device and there's not a lot of room around the panel to install it.  The BRNSURGE could be installed in any open two slot space in the panel which is much easier (would still need to move a few breakers to make room though).  However, I could just use the BR230SUR to replace an existing 30amp two pole breaker and from what I understand get similar protection to the BRNSURGE without taking up any spare slots.

What I can't determine is if there a marked difference in effectiveness between the three options.  I'm assuming the CHSPT2ULTRA has a much higher capacity than the two breaker options, but I'm not sure if that higher capacity is worth the effort of getting it installed. Additionally, I can't tell if there's a big difference in effectiveness between the two breaker options.  I'm assuming the stand alone device - BRSURGE - is more capable than the combined device -BR230SUR - but I'm not sure I can tell from reading the specs.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here are the spec sheet for the devices in question if that's helpful.

BRNSURGE - https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.BRNSURGE.specifications.html

BR230SUR - https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.BR230SUR.specifications.html

CHSPT2ULTRA - https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.CHSPT2ULTRA.specifications.html

https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/residential/electrical-safety/nec-surge-protection-cc003013en.pdf

Comment: How can there not be room around the panel?  Your panel isn't 8' tall is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the panel is mounted between two studs and the top is where the incoming and outgoing lines are.  It's also surrounded by insulation. That's why I was leaning towards the 30-amp breaker combo since it would a relatively simple DIY install. The CHSPT2ULTRA has a higher maximum capacity than the two breaker options (108 kA vs. 38 kA) and also offers more modes of protection than the breaker types L-N/L-G/L-L/N-G vs. just L-N, L-L . The biggest difference between the devices seems to be the maximum surge capacity and the N-G mode of protection offered by the external device.